# If swipe down on iOS7 gives Notification Centre, where's Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight, notifications, ios

I just upgraded to iOS 7 on an iPhone 4S. When I swipe down on any screen, I get Notification Center, not Spotlight. Anyone know which setting is wrong?

My Google search results are riddled with "Spotlight does work, you just swipe down!" articles, so no luck there. Control Center works just fine, if that helps. Disabling Notification Center explicitly on the lock screen also works, such that nothing happens on a swipe down on the lock screen if it's disabled. But Spotlight isn't showing up on a swipe down from regular screens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get to Spotlight, just swipe down somewhere in the middle of the screen, not from the top (on any home screen, not in an app and not while locked).

Comment: And also not over the dock at the bottom of the screen.